# Symfony 3 composer update ContextErrorException

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to implement a Symfony2 project (from Ubuntu 14.04) in Symfony 3 for Ubuntu 16.04, and I've hit a bit of a wall. When I run composer update (verbose) I receive the following exception and trace at the end, and I'm not really sure how to clear it up. I know I'm doing something wrong, but the exception isn't exactly helpful in pinning down where the problem might be. Has anyone run into this problem before and know some likely culprits?

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()           


Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:  





    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                
    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()                         





Exception trace:
 () at /vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:293
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::executeCommand() at /vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:143
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache() at /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:238
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->executeEventPhpScript() at /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:192
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:79
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() at /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:177
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:94
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php:337
 Composer\Installer->run() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:173
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:841
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:189
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:166
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:120
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:99
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at /usr/bin/composer:44
```

Comment: Since it's clearCache that is failing I'd try to just force-delete (manually) the contents of the cache folder and see if that resolved the issue

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't.

Comment: find a recently added code that contains foreach with null as argument in console command or new bundle that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed/added a lib and forgot to remove/add it from AppKernel?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case.